# asynchronous guzzle call to a function while seeding in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, guzzle, laravel-seeding

I am trying to fetch geocodes from an api and update in my database against address entries. I am running this through a seed class in laravel.

And **I am using Guzzle to make an asynchronous call. I want to run the api calls asynchronously while at the same time I want to read the asynchronous response in the background and update them in the database.**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
//retrieve the the latitude and longitude from geocode.farm of the given address
$response = $client->get('http:........<url for json request goes here>',['future' => true]);
$response->then(function ($response) {
  // in here I read the $response object and get the latitude /longitude to update in the database.
```

// I tried to echo and print here, it seems the script is not entering here in this callback function
    });

I am calling the above line of code in a loop. The above script runs fine when I make a synchronous call, but in asynchronous call I am unable to run it? can you please help me with it.

the script doesn't seem to enter in the callback function

Comment: The async call may be failing, and therefore not entering the success callback.  Try adding an error callback method as well, and see if it is getting in there.  The error callback method is just a second closure parameter to the `then()` method.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too! The script isn't entering the callback function when run through artisan... Did you find a way?

Comment: I sort of could not find a solution to it and I moved on to a different project, but this mystery still haunts me in my dreams